# jquery mouseenter with live() doesn't work on chrome and explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do something when the user hovers on the container, regardless of its children. As I understand it should look something like this:

```
$('.element').live({
    mouseenter: function() { console.log('entered'); },
    mouseleave: function() { console.log('exited'); }
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="element">
    <div>
        <img src="aaa.png">
        <div>aa</div>
        <div>
            <div>a</div>
            <div>b</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        blabla
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason this doesn't work. When I hover over the element, it still listens to hover events on the child elements and logs. Maybe because it is live?

Comment: I don't follow what your problem is... `entered` and `exited` are logged when the mouse moves over/out of the `.element` element. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @James When I open this page, it logs even inside the element, when I'm hovering in and out of inner divs. I'm expecting it to ignore the inner structure of element, and just tell me when the cursor entered/left the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently it's a bug in jquery 1.60. Once I switched to 1.62 everything started working as expected.

Answer (score -2):

-- edit: wrong idea --

http://jsfiddle.net/dRaw6/ seems to work

Comment: I was under the impression that onmouseover and mouseenter are different - the latter preventing bubble up. If what you are saying is true, what is the difference between these events?
Anyhow, how do you stop the bubble up of all the children elements' events?

Comment: Also what you suggested doesn't work, it is still logging on child events.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't see the mouseover/mouseenter difference. I guess I went in the wrong direction because of that.

Comment: Interesting. So it's a bug in chrome and explorer?? (I checked both)

Comment: No, chrome/Firefox/IE work for me actually. But the elements stretch over the page for me now, maybe that's not the case in your test?

Comment: I found the answer... it's a bug in jquery 1.60. works perfectly on 1.62